# "in the hundreds" vs "in hundreds"

Tags: difference, definite-article, zero-article, numbers

I'd like to know the difference between "*in the hundreds*" and "*in hundreds*". For this purpose I've found some examples:

> [collinsdictionary.com](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/the-hundreds): **1a** *The temperature was **in the hundreds***.
>
> my variant without "*the*": **1b** *The temperature was **in hundreds***.

> [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/hundreds): **2a** *Property loss was only **in the hundreds** of dollars*.
>
> my variant without "*the*": **2b** *Property loss was only **in hundreds** of dollars*.

> [oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/hundred): **3a** *Men died **in the hundreds***.
>
> my variant without "*the*": **3b** *Men died **in hundreds***.

> [oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/hundred): **4a** *We're talking about a figure **in the low hundreds***.
>
> my variant without "*the*": **4b** *We're talking about a figure **in low hundreds***.

> [cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/example/english/hundreds-and-thousands) **5a** *I have seen the police **in hundreds and thousands***.
>
> my variant with "*the*": **5b** *I have seen the police **in the hundreds and thousands***.

> [cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/example/english/hundreds-and-thousands) **6a** *Alas, we think **in hundreds and thousands** and just occasionally **in tens**.*
>
> my variant with "*the*": **6b** *Alas, we think **in the hundreds and thousands** and just occasionally **in the tens***.

> [lexico.com](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/quickstep) **7a** *The foxtrot is still danced every night of the week **in hundreds** of modern sequence dance clubs around the country, along with the waltz, quickstep, tango, rhumba, cha cha, jive, mambo, salsa, saunter, blues, swing and so on*.
>
> my variant with "*the*": **7b** *The foxtrot is still danced every night of the week **in the hundreds** of modern sequence dance clubs around the country, along with the waltz, quickstep, tango, rhumba, cha cha, jive, mambo, salsa, saunter, blues, swing and so on*.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When speaking of temperatures or sums of money, it has to be *in the hundreds*, meaning *in the range of figures above 100%* or *between $100 and $999*.

*In hundreds* usually means *in groups of around 100* or *in numbers large enough to be estimated as multiples of 100.*

Your Longman link doesn't take me to the definition in question! However, your variant including *the* is acceptable, but I think it gives a different shade of meaning. *In hundreds of dance clubs* could mean that there are over 1,000 such clubs, but the foxtrot is danced in only several hundred of them. *In the hundreds of dance clubs* would mean that there are several hundred clubs and the foxtrot is danced in all of them.

Comment: 1) I've checked the link №7 - it works! The sentence will be shown there, if you press the "more example sentences" button under the first definition on that site. 2) I've added the seventh sentence in full, because you said this is important to its meaning.